# How can I call a page once in Jetpack compose viewPager?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lottie

How can I call this only once?

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun TutorialPager(
    tutorials: List<TutorialViewModel.TutorialUiResources>,
    state: PagerState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    HorizontalPager(
        count = tutorials.size,
        state = state,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        userScrollEnabled = false
    ) {
        TutorialPage(state.currentPage, pagerScope = this, tutorial = tutorials[currentPage])
    }
}
```

And also TutorialPage is called many times. I just want to call it just once when it's visible.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun TutorialPage(
    currentPage: Int,
    pagerScope: PagerScope,
    tutorial: TutorialViewModel.TutorialUiResources,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val isShow = currentPage == pagerScope.currentPage
    val pxValue = LocalDensity.current.run { 60.dp.toPx() }
 
    if(isShow){
        Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visibleState = MutableTransitionState(false).apply { targetState = isShow },
                enter = pageItemSlideInTransition(pxValue.toInt(), 100)
            ) {
                Log.d("aos", "World: page:${pagerScope.currentPage}, ${tutorial.lottie}")
//                Lottie(
//                    currentPage == pagerScope.currentPage,
//                    tutorial.lottie,
//                    modifier = Modifier
//                        .align(Alignment.TopStart)
//                        .size(220.dp),
//                    speed = 0.3f
//                )
            }

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
            ) {
                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visibleState = MutableTransitionState(false).apply { targetState = isShow },
                    enter = pageItemSlideInTransition(pxValue.toInt(), 250)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(id = tutorial.titleRes),
                        fontFamily = HanSansFamily,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge,
                        color = Color.Black
                    )
                }

                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visibleState = MutableTransitionState(false).apply { targetState = isShow },
                    enter = pageItemSlideInTransition(pxValue.toInt(), 400)
                ) {
                    Spacer(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(vertical = 20.dp)
                            .size(width = 28.dp, height = 4.dp)
                            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary, shape = RoundedCornerShape(100))
                    )
                }

                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visibleState = MutableTransitionState(false).apply { targetState = isShow },
                    enter = pageItemSlideInTransition(pxValue.toInt(), 550)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(id = tutorial.subTitleRes),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                        lineHeight = 22.4.sp,
                        color = Color.Gray05
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Those composable functions are called many times, and it has Lottie files. So, I guess they are loaded many times. And it cause 'OutOfMemory' Erorr.

Here's my log when the app is launched.

```
17:30:56.215 aos          D  Hello!
17:30:56.263 aos          D  ===================
17:30:56.263 aos          D  Hello: page:0, 2131886082
17:30:56.268 aos          D  World: page:0, 2131886082
17:30:56.303 aos          D  ===================
17:30:56.303 aos          D  Hello: page:0, 2131886082
17:30:56.305 aos          D  World: page:0, 2131886082
17:30:56.368 aos          D  Hello!
17:30:56.392 aos          D  World: page:0, 2131886082
17:30:56.394 aos          D  World: page:0, 2131886082
17:30:56.771 aos          D  World: page:0, 2131886082
17:30:56.773 aos          D  World: page:0, 2131886082
17:30:56.789 aos          D  World: page:0, 2131886082
17:30:56.791 aos          D  World: page:0, 2131886082
```

Hello!  >> TutorialPager()
===== >> TutorialPage()

And this is when the next page is visible after swiping.

```
17:36:43.077 aos          D  ===================
17:36:43.077 aos          D  Hello: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.079 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.085 aos          D  ===================
17:36:43.086 aos          D  Hello: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.088 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.093 aos          D  ===================
17:36:43.093 aos          D  Hello: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.095 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.140 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.143 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.150 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.283 aos          D  ===================
17:36:43.283 aos          D  Hello: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.284 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.305 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.554 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.568 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.669 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.684 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.704 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
17:36:43.718 aos          D  World: page:1, 2131886083
```

This is Lottie function.

```
@Composable
fun Lottie(play: Boolean, @RawRes lottie: Int, modifier: Modifier = Modifier, speed: Float = 1f, iterations: Int = LottieConstants.IterateForever) {
    val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(lottie))

    val lottieAnimatable = rememberLottieAnimatable()

    LaunchedEffect(composition) {
        lottieAnimatable.animate(
            composition = composition,
            clipSpec = LottieClipSpec.Frame(0, 1200),
            initialProgress = 0f
        )
    }

    val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
        composition,
        isPlaying = play,
        speed = speed,
        iterations = iterations
    )

    LottieAnimation(
        composition = composition,
        progress = { progress },
        modifier = modifier
    )
}
```

Comment: I wonder what happens when you remove any type of animation, like for instance, remove `AnimatedVisibility` and any animation, Instead use a `if(anyConditionThatMakesVisible) { content }`. I'm assuming what's causing that is the animation and unstable types like a `List<T>`. But that's my first guess without taking a deeper look in the code, just because I've faced that in the past

Comment: @Barrufet I need to give animation for views. That's why I am using them.

Comment: of course. But if you remove the animations, it's probable that you see less calls recompositions to `TutorialPager` which would mean that there are functions that can't be skipped. Given that you don't wanna do a quick check by removing the animations then I recommend you to check out "Compiler Metrics" and see the reports by yourself. If you have more questions, please feel free to do them once you've done this

Comment: what is `Lottie`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Lottie is an animation library from Airbnb.

Comment: Not what I mean, I know that much. But this isn't what their readme example usage looks like, so I figured `Lottie {}` is a custom composable

Comment: "How can I call this only once?" -- if your implementation relies on a composable only being called once, your implementation is broken. Your composables will get recomposed many, many times. "I need to give animation for views" -- then use some sort of an [effect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) to arrange to have the animation only be applied once.

Answer (score 0):

Use launch effect block. That should do the trick

Comment: Well, I don't know how to apply it. Could you explain it more please?

Comment: Check documentation. its easy to understand

Comment: Are you sure that you've tried that before?

Comment: Of course. Have you not tried it? It’s literally a line of code. Well a block u create using LaunchEffect..

Comment: As I updated, I used LaunchEffect. But still the same. I already used it.